# how to remove first and last spaces in php

Tags: php, string

```
 $search = substr($search_string, 0, -1);
```

It is only removing last one space only. Some times in last character after having 2 or more spaces how to remove all spaces after word last character and if some times end user entered first character space how to remove also first character?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
   $s = "  blabla   ";
   $s = trim($s, " ");
```

Comment: Don't necessarily have to give that whitespace as a second argument there, that is default

Comment: $s = "  blabla   ";
$s = trim($s, " "); it is working fine thanking you Bart and who are replaying me

Comment: but it's not good for two sentence.

Answer (score 4):

use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

```
$search_string = trim($search_string);
```

Answer (score 3):

`trim()` is probably what you are looking for. It removes all the whitespaces from both sides of a string.

```
$search = trim($search);
```

You can also see `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` for removing the whitespaces from only one side of the string (left or right).

```
$search = ltrim($search);
$search = rtrim($search);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use trim() function
try:

```
$search = trim($search);
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a PHP function for this.

Use PHP's [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function.